# R: Counting the Number of Times a Condition Appears in a Data Frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I thought of the following question I would like to test:

- Suppose there is a coin that has a 5% chance of landing on HEADS and a 95% chance of landing on tails

Based on a computer simulation, I want to find out the following :

- The  minimum number of flips before observing HEADS, TAILS, HEADS
- The  average number of flips before observing HEADS, TAILS, HEADS
- The  maximum number of flips before observing HEADS, TAILS, HEADS

I tried to write a simulation in R that flips this coin three times, I call this a "run". The simulation then performs 100 "runs":

```
results <- list()

for (i in 1:100){

response_i <- c("H","T")
response_i <- sample(response_i, 3, replace=TRUE, 
                        prob=c(0.05, 0.95))
response_i <- as.factor(response_i)

iteration_i = i

run_i = data.frame(response_i, iteration_i)

 results[[i]] <- run_i

}
```

This looks as follows (e.g. run #22, #23, #24):

```
[[22]]
  response_i iteration_i
1          T          22
2          T          22
3          T          22

[[23]]
  response_i iteration_i
1          H          23
2          T          23
3          T          23

[[24]]
  response_i iteration_i
1          T          24
2          T          24
3          T          24
```

**My Question:**

I would like to modify the above code so that:

**1)** The simulation automatically stops after you see the first H, T, H (right now, I run the simulation for 100 runs, and hope this is enough runs to observe at least one H, T, T)

**2)** Once the first H, T, H appears and the simulation automatically stops, I would like to record at which "run" this took place (i.e. what was the value of "iteration_i"? )

**3)** I would then like to repeat this entire simulation 100 times (100 runs * 100 times = 10,000  coin flips)

Once this is completed, I will be able to make histograms which show the  minimum number of  coin flips, the average number of coin flips and the  maximum number of coin flips before H, T, H was observed (using "ggplot2", I don't think this will be too difficult).

```
#sample data
number_of_runs_before_HTH_appeared = c(15,10, 11, 8, 12, 21, 32, 7, 9, 20, 22, 3, 16, 7 )

hist(number_of_runs_before_HTH_appeared, main = "Number of Runs before HTH")
```

[image]

But can someone please help me format/modify my code to simplify what I am trying to achieve? At the moment, I used the following R code to "tidy up" the 100 "runs" from the first simulation:

```
results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

 head(results_df)
  response_i iteration_i
1          T           1
2          T           1
3          T           1
4          T           2
5          T           2
6          T           2
```

I then manually repeated this many times, e..g

```
results_df_1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
results_df_1$index = 1

#re-run original simulation
results_df_2<- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
results_df_2$index = 2

#re-run original simulation (many times)
results_df_n<- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
results_df_n$index = n

final <- data.frame(results_df_1, results_df_2, results_df_n)
```

I then imported this "final" file into Microsoft Excel and tried to manually collapse the "final file" to answer my three original questions - but I was hoping that someone could show me how to do this by modifying my original code in R.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of for and while loop will serve your purpose.

***for*** loop will run the times you want to repeat the test and ***while*** loop will help you to stop the test when the first H T H combination occurs.

Below is the code you can use and proceed with the further steps.

```
results <- list()

for (j in 1:100) {

  response_i <- ''
  i <- 1

  while (response_i != 'HTH') {
    response_i <- c("H","T")
    response_i <- sample(response_i, 3, replace=TRUE, 
                         prob=c(0.05, 0.95))
    response_i <- paste(response_i, collapse = '')

    iteration_i = i
    if (response_i == 'HTH') {
      run_i = data.frame(response_i, iteration_i)
      results[[j]] <- run_i
      }
    i <- i + 1
  }
}

data <- do.call('rbind', results)

head(data)

      response_i iteration_i
1        HTH        1206
2        HTH          46
3        HTH         116
4        HTH        1633
5        HTH         889
6        HTH          43
```

Comment: @ Sayed: Thank you for your answer! Why is the paste/collapse line necessary? why have you not written : for (j in 1:100) and for (i in 1:100)? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! 
paste and collapse are required to get the combination of strings into a single string for eg. A <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z') is a vector and paste(A) will return "X" "Y" "Z" whereas paste(A, collapse = '') will return a string as "XYZ" which is a better way to compare. Also for iterating within for loop I have used j because i is already used in while loop

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started

```
library(data.table)
n <- 100
simulations <- 100
# build data.table with simulations
DT <- data.table(sim = rep(1:simulations, each = n),
                 step = 1:n,
                 flip = lapply(
                   lapply(seq.int(n * simulations), 
                          function(x) sample(c("H","T"), 3, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.05, 0.95))),
                   paste0, collapse = ""))
#        sim step flip
#     1:   1    1  TTT
#     2:   1    2  TTT
#     3:   1    3  TTT
#     4:   1    4  TTT
#     5:   1    5  TTT
#    ---              
#  9996: 100   96  THT
#  9997: 100   97  TTT
#  9998: 100   98  TTT
#  9999: 100   99  TTT
# 10000: 100  100  TTT

DT
# find the first step where flip == "HTH" for each sim
DT[flip == "HTH", .(first_hth = min(step)), by = .(sim)]
#     sim first_hth
#  1:   2        88
#  2:   6        30
#  3:   7        16
#  4:  19        38
#  5:  26        42
#  6:  28        91
#  7:  34        87
#  8:  36        96
#  9:  38        98
# 10:  45        74
# 11:  48        93
# 12:  51        46
# 13:  53        30
# 14:  60        70
# 15:  68        27
# 16:  69        53
# 17:  88        35
# 18:  91        88
# 19:  94        74
# 20:  95       100
# 21:  97        81
# 22:  98        24
#     sim first_hth
```

Comment: @ Wimpel : Thank you for your answer! Your R code uses functions that I haven't studied! Can I ask you some questions about them?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
coin_flip <- crossing(trial = seq_len(1000),
                flips = 1:1000) %>% 
  mutate(heads = rbinom(n(), 1, .05)) %>% 
  group_by(trial) %>% 
  mutate(second_flip = lead(heads),
         third_flip = lead(heads,2),
         hth = heads & !second_flip & third_flip) %>% 
  summarise(first_hth = which(hth)[1]+2) 
coin_flip %>% head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   trial first_hth
#>   <int>     <dbl>
#> 1     1        46
#> 2     2        31
#> 3     3       114
#> 4     4        NA
#> 5     5       776
#> 6     6       292
coin_flip %>% ggplot(aes(first_hth))+
  geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 96 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>